# Moving WordPress From Local Server to Live Site : HTTP 500 ERROR

Tags: database, wordpress, live

I created a website on localhost and it looks/works perfectly, but when I am moving it to live site, nothing shows up. I did everything according to this tutorial: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

I am using a local hosting and they use cpanel where I upload all my files to a folder www/mysite.ru. But once I completed all the steps from above tutorial it shows: HTTP 500 ERROR.

Any ideas on what could be causing a problem would be very much appreciated. Thank u in advance!